# Usage of spring dependencies spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors and spring-cloud-spring-service-connector

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I was going through a spring project and came across the 2 `dependencies spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors` and `spring-cloud-spring-service-connector` where the developer claimed to have used these 2 dependencies to connect to cloud foundry. I was not able to get a clear understanding and difference between the 2 dependencies after searching over internet. Please provide the usage of these 2 dependencies and how the 2 can be majorly differentiated.